# Image not displaying in imageview from camera and Gallery in Device, works on emulator

Tags: android

Iam developing an application where the user can set image in image view by capturing from camera or by selecting from gallery...the code works fine in emulator But in devices it doesnt.The camera works fine the image get saved in gallery but it doesnt appear in the imageview.Same case while selecting from gallery..while checking in emulator works fine but in device. the problem arises..

Here is the Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     ImageView viewImage;
        Button b;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
            viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectImage();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds options to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

          private void selectImage() {

            final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }
                    else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                    }
                    else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                    for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                        if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                            f = temp;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap;
                        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                                bitmapOptions); 

                        viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        String path = android.os.Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator
                                + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                        f.delete();
                        OutputStream outFile = null;
                        File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                        try {
                            outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                            outFile.flush();
                            outFile.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                    c.close();
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                }
            }
        }   

}



Manifest:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imagetest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.imagetest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main activity layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dp" >

  <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Photo" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help...
Thanks..

Comment: Do you have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: Sir the Problem showing in certain models of device...ised that permission too but not working..

Comment: Which is why I asked-  some devices are strict about external storage, some aren't.

Comment: This is because you need to decode that file because it will be big size while capturing in camera or from gallery so you need to decode it.

Comment: Ok sir ,How to accomplish it...

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377186/decode-file-from-sdcard-android-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error-due-to-large-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial and demo. it's so easy
 [How to pick image from gallery](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-pick-image-from-gallery/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).