# getting OutOfMemoryError on image load from file

Tags: android

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377186/decode-file-from-sdcard-android-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error-due-to-large-bitmap), and from what I can tell, I'm effectively doing the same thing as what the top answer suggested. But I'm still getting the outOfMemory crash on devices with less memory.

EDIT: I'm just taking a picture with the phones native camera. Nothing fanncy.

```
private Bitmap setImgViewFromFile(ImageView imgView, String file) {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = Math.max(imgView.getWidth(), 600);
    int targetH = Math.max(imgView.getHeight(), 800);


    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmOptions);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
12-10 10:38:04.120    4144-4144/com.loop E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.loop, PID: 4144
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:613)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:589)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:369)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bear in mind that there is no guarantee that any particular sample size will work, as there is no guarantee that there is a free memory block big enough for any given bitmap.

Comment: Your calculation of the scale is not ok. But as you will scale down now too much it will not cause the out of memory error. Do devices with little memory have screens bigger than 800x600?

Comment: Only powers of two are guaranteed as scale factor. What is the resolution of that camera. And of the camera where you go out of memory?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
// Determine how much to scale down the image
int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);
```

to

```
// Determine how much to scale down the image
int scaleFactor = findBestSampleSize(photoW , photoH ,targetW,targetH);
```

that `findBestSampleSize` is:

```
/**
 * Returns the largest power-of-two divisor for use in downscaling a bitmap
 * that will not result in the scaling past the desired dimensions.
 *
 * @param actualWidth Actual width of the bitmap
 * @param actualHeight Actual height of the bitmap
 * @param desiredWidth Desired width of the bitmap
 * @param desiredHeight Desired height of the bitmap
 */
// Visible for testing.
static int findBestSampleSize(
        int actualWidth, int actualHeight, int desiredWidth, int desiredHeight) {
    double wr = (double) actualWidth / desiredWidth;
    double hr = (double) actualHeight / desiredHeight;
    double ratio = Math.min(wr, hr);
    float n = 1.0f;
    while ((n * 2) <= ratio) {
        n *= 2;
    }

    return (int) n;
}
```

if still getting `OOM` change `float n = 1.0f;` to `float n = 2.0f;` or `float n = 4.0f;` or ...

Comment: thanks @mmlooloo, could you please explain what the while loop is doing? according to the documentation, "the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2."

Comment: It finds the closest power of 2 which is less than or equal of the ratio. it begins from 1 and multiply by 2 till it gets less than or equal of ratio. In other words "a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2"

Comment: but if the api is already doing that, why does it need to be done manually? is it for efficiency?

Comment: the api dose not scale the image, the idea is if you want to show a large image in a small frame you do not need to show all pixels so remove as much as you can.

Comment: sorry to keep bugging, I think you miss understood my question. The Doc says "a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2", doesnt this imply that system will round it down to the nearest power of 2? or did they mean to say "YOU (the developer) must round it down to the power of two"?