# Show hd image in a imageview from sd card

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I just making a simple program which show a HD images that is in sdcard of phone. My code is this

```
    ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    File f = new File("/sdcard/mytestdownloadedfile2.jpg");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

when i running my code it not show any image but when i change this HD photo to a standered photo or png. It show it without any problem. So please help me.

Comment: try the code in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377186/decode-file-from-sdcard-android-to-avoid-out-of-memory-error-due-to-large-bitmap

Comment: Could you please share image or indicate the image Colorspace.

Comment: That is the link (http://wallpaperswide.com/download/the_forbidden_forest-wallpaper-2560x1440.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method to decode file , let me know if it works

```
public static Bitmap decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(String filePath,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
}
```

Comment: Sir i am not want to change my photo quality i just showing  only one hd image in my image view.

Comment: is it possible to do so.